# Reading a *.reg file using VC++ MFC

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, registry

I am trying to read a registry file  (*.reg) file using VC++ MFC .

Now I am trying to read the registry file line by line . So are there any other alternative way to read the file  ?

Thanks and Regards,
Sid

Answer (score 1):

No, the .reg format is an an "undocumented" format to the Microsoft Registry Editor (regedit), so there is no API that provides a higher level access.  However, it is simple to just read the lines as you are doing.